# When the answer of a question sounds crystal clear to you and you can answer without any further question

Tags: idioms

Imagine you have a conversation with someone else e.g. your friend and he wants to ask you about something which it's answer is completely clear to you.

There is an idiom in my language which says:

It is like a painting that... [Meaning that everything is clear to you and the facts acknowledge that...]

In the Cambridge dictionary I found a possible equivalent for the meaning in my question:

Example:

> - Person A) Who do you think is better-looking, Jennifer Lopez or Jessica Alba?
> - Person B) That’s a complete [no-brainier](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/no-brainer)! Jessica Alba is much better-looking.

However, I doubt if it (the idiom "no-brainier") is the most clear to what I am looking for.

I need to know find out how an AE speaker would say it?

Comment: no-brain**er**.  I can't think of another idiom, though.

Comment: perhaps "Don't you get it?  Or, "It is so obvious to me." These are just everyday language though.

Comment: @WillowRex I didn't undesrand you well. Does it work in the meaning that I'm looking for?

Comment: "Come on A! Jessica Alba is way better looking! It's so obvious!  Or, "What don't you get? Alba is sexier, smarter and younger than Lopez. It's a no-brainer!" The difference between two beautiful women doesn't work as well as some comparisons, but I am trying to work with what you used as an example.

Comment: @WillowRex as far as I understood "no-brainier" works well here. Right?

Comment: You are not spelling it correctly. no Brainer, there's only one 'i'' ... brain **er**. Brainier means more brainy. The 'ier' would make brainy a comparative adjective. Brain**er** is slang. No brainer means it is obvious. Brainier means *even smarter*, and does not fit here.

Comment: You are right. It was slipped. :) Thank you very much fo the help @WillowRex ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are idioms that also mean "It seems crystal clear* to me." These fit this specific example of comparing two similar things, in this case attractive and successful women. *This is a perfect idiom that you already know how to use appropriately.

> "**It goes without saying**, that Alba is is more attractive."
>
> "**Of course**, Alba is more attractive."
>
> "**Needless to say**, Alba is more attractive.

Answer (score 2):

In that context, my answer would probably be:

> Jessica Alba, obviously.

If you want more interesting idioms, do any of [these](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/topics/being-and-existing/apparent-and-obvious/) help?